# Multi domains to multi instances

Tags: vps, odoo

I want to host two odoo instances or database (?), in order to be sure that everything is separated, on a rented VPS for my wife firm and mine.
We both have a domain name.

I need the following thing : 
- Browsing www.mywifedomainname.tld leads to my wife's odoo
- Browsing www.myowndomainname.tld leads to my odoo instance

Can you advise me what to do :
1 - Do I need a reverse proxy to have multi domains leading to multi instances ?
2 - In case the reverse proxy is the solution, do you know a good tutorial on how to setup it on Debian (or another distribution) ?
3 - Should I have 2 instances of Odoo or only 2 databases ?

Thanks for you interest :)

Comment: Odoo developer write that it's easy. Look at here: https://www.linkedin.com/groups/Can-we-use-multi-domain-165657.S.5920126268984012804

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes i have realized this on my server.
to achieve that goal I have tested two ways. It's up to you wich one is better to feet on your needs
1 method is odoo+wsgi+appache2
2 method is odoo+nginx+SSL
both cases required the proxy reverse.
so lest go on.
I assume that you know how to install odoo and postgress
mandatory requirement:

1. you should have hardware that can handle odoo postgress and webserver for more than one instance. As of every instance of odoo creates it's own processes. My server (6 core CPU, 3 gb Ram, and i have cpu load around 5% and RAM for 40%, i have 6 different instances rub=ning on this server with different domain names)
2. for each instance you should have different user created for odoo and for PostgreSQL

in case of using first method odoo+wsgi+appach you don't ned to configure openerp-server.conf file and sturtuo script as of we gonna use openerp-wsgi.py file as a configuration and the appache to sturt odoo.

**/YOUR_ODOO1_PATH/openerp-wsgi.py** modification with your data:

---

```
conf['addons_path'] = 'LINK TO YOUR ODOO1 ADDONS FULL PATH FROM THE ROOT'

admin_passwd = 'ODOO1 MASTR ADMIN PASSWORD'

conf['db_user'] = 'ODOO1_POSTGRESQL_USER_NAME'

conf['db_password'] = 'ODOO1_POSTGRESQL_USER_PASSWORD'

bind = '0.0.0.0:8070'

pidfile = '.gunicorn.pid'

workers = 4

timeout = 240

max_requests = 2000

conf['logfile'] = '/var/log/ODOO1/wsgi-pyton.log'
```

---

**THAT WILL RUN YOUR ODOO1 instance on port 8070**

for each instance you should use **DIFFERENT PORT**

now it is time to configure appache server:
I assume that you have installed apache server
but in any case, to do that use

```
sudo apt-get install apache2
```

and for mod WSGI

```
sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-wsgi
```

3. Enable required apache modules:

   sudo a2enmod proxy_http headers rewrite wsgi

If the system miss some of them you should install this modules first then enable them. More you will find in the Apache website.

4. Create Configuration file in apache for reverse proxy for site odoo1.com:

   sudo nano /etc/apache2/sites-available/odoo1.conf

> ```
> <VirtualHost *:80>
> ServerName odoo1.com
> ErrorLog /var/log/odoo1/openerp-error.log
> CustomLog /var/log/odoo1/openerp-access.log combined
> <Proxy *>
> Order deny,allow
> Allow from all
> </Proxy>
> ProxyRequests Off
> ProxyPass / **odoo1_full_URL**
> ProxyPassReverse / **odoo1_full_URL**
> ProxyVia On
> LogLevel warn
> </VirtualHost>
> ```

**odoo1_full_URL** replace with **http : // odoo1.com: 8070** (for me it is not allowed to post more than 2 url, that way i have write in this way without spaces)
5. Create Site Configuration file to run WSGI script

```
sudo nano /etc/apache2/site-available/odoo1-wsgi.conf
```

With following content

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName odoo1.com
WSGIScriptAlias / /YOUR_ODOO1_PATH/openerp-wsgi.py
WSGIDaemonProcess oe user=ODOO1_USER group=ODOO1_USER processes=2 pythonpath=/YOUR_ODOO1_Path/ display-name=apache-ODOO1USER
WSGIProcessGroup oe
ErrorLog /var/log/ODOO1/odoo1-wsgi-error.log
CustomLog /var/log/ODOO1/odoo1-wsgi-access.log combined
<Directory /YOUR_ODOO1_PATH>
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

6. finaly enable your odoo1 and odoo1-wsgi configuration sites and restart apache server

   sudo a2ensite odoo1-wsgi.conf odoo1.conf
   sudo service apache2 restart

that's all by typing in the url the odoo1.com you will be able to see your database without port number in the address bar.

do the same for any other instance and enjoy.
Let me know if you will have questions.
teh second method I will explain in my next post.

Comment: I'm confused, I had not see your answer before :'(
I haven't put my Odoos in production yet because I got some customization problems with it but your answer is very clear and it seems easy to set up !
By the way many thanks for your time and your answer !